# Who or what is Scotty's helper?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-reboot

In the new Star Trek movies (2009, 2013) Scotty is seen with an alien friend/helper.

Who and/or what is this creature and does it have a counterpart to any being in the Original Series?

Comment: +1 Nice one, I once wanted to ask this question after I had re-watched the 2009 movie, but I forgot. :S

Answer (score 21, accepted):

His name is Keenser and he's played by actor Deep Roy. There's not much info on him so far that I could find.
Keenser is a Roylan or Royla.
I don't recall the original Scotty ever having a sidekick.
Here's a link for canon star trek: [link](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Keenser)
And here's another link about Keenser but I can't tell if it's canon: [link](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Keenser)

Comment: The second image looks older, from an older animated series. http://images3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130424171655/startrek/images/thumb/9/9d/Keenser_(2258).jpg/225px-Keenser_(2258).jpg

Comment: That image is not from the animated series, but rather from a comic book.

Comment: _Deep Roy_ 100% sounds like a pornstars name.

Answer (score 10):

All the following information is from the apocrypha section on Keenser from Memory-Alpha:

The name of Keenser's species was not stated in either of the movies. Keenser was the protagonist of the fourteenth issue of IDW Publishing's Star Trek, which identifies Keenser as a Roylan from the planet of Royla, where he lived with his parents.

He was often ridiculed by his so-called "friends" because he was taller than all the others of his kind. In 2230, after first contact with his people was made by the Federation Starfleet ship USS Kelvin, Keenser demonstrated his engineering skills to the Kelvin's first officer Lt. Cmdr. George Kirk and security officer Lt. K'Bentayr by giving them a complete diagnostic and pinpointing the problem.

With his parents' best wishes, Keenser was allowed to leave with Kelvin's away team. He experienced space sickness on the way to Kelvin. In the alternate reality, Keenser was one of the survivors of Nero's attack on the USS Kelvin. He graduated from the Starfleet Academy in 2233, becoming the first Roylan to have left Royla and to join Starfleet. He dedicated his service to the fallen George Kirk.

Answer (score 7):

This is **Ensign Keenser**, a Starfleet Academy Graduate and a member of Starfleet's Engineering corp. He has an extensive write-up on [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Keenser) and the following info about him appears on the [official StarTrek.com website](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/keenser).

> A native of a sentient, spacefaring species that may or may not be a Federation member in the Nero-derived alternate timeline year 2358. In Keenser’s case, natives are either mute, telepathic, or unable or unwilling to use universal translators to speak verbally. Keenser was the only company Montgomery Scott had during an assignment at the automated Federation outpost on the ice world Delta-Vega, and endured the silent end of a love-hate relationship with the Scotsman.
>
> He was left behind after the visiting Spock and Kirk took Scott with them back to the U.S.S. Enterprise, but Keenser eventually wound up with his onetime supervisor as an engineer on the ship.

---

There's a lot more detail about his life and background in the Star Trek Ongoing comic ([v1 #14](http://www.idwpublishing.com/product/star-trek-ongoing-14/)), some of it *slightly* contradictory with what's established in the films

**His planet (Royla) was '*first-contacted*' by the Kelvin (including George Kirk)**
[image]

**He was the first of his kind to leave the planet and the first to graduate from Starfleet Academy**
[image]

**He served on a number of ships and space stations before being assigned to Delta Vega. Subsequently he was promoted to Lieutenant and made Chief Engineer.**
[image]

**Unfortunately, he basically got forgotten by Starfleet after the frontier moved outwards**
[image]

### Out of Universe

His species (the Roylans) were an original creation for the Star Trek reboot.  Keenser does speak, but he only has a [single line of dialogue](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0796366/quotes?item=qt0999483) in the films. This isn't the first time that [this joke](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Morn) has been used in the Star Trek universe.

> **Q:** *Let’s go back to Star Trek (2009) for a moment. How did you land the role of Keenser?*
>
> **ROY:** *I was introduced to J.J. Abrams by the art director. They were looking for me. My good friend, Tommy Harper, who is the
> co-producer/production manager, was the one who recommended me. I was
> introduced to J.J. and he hired me, and that’s how it started.*
>
> **Q:** *Was the plan always that Keenser would almost not talk at all, or did that happen organically?*
>
> **ROY:** *I had dialogue, but they changed that. They said, “It doesn’t look right for this guy to talk because, after all, he’s from
> another planet. He’s an alien. He doesn’t speak the language.” So
> that’s what happened on the first film. I did have dialogue, but they
> took it out. J.J. told me why and I said, “Sure, whatever it is, it
> is.” And then it just made sense for him not to speak in the second
> one, either.*
>
> <sub><sup>[EXCLUSIVE INTERVIEW: Deep Roy, Scotty's Alien Pal, Keenser](http://www.startrek.com/article/exclusive-interview-deep-roy-scottys-alien-pal-keenser#sthash.6RHyZ5ql.dpuf)</sup></sub>

Answer (score -1):

You're right, OS Scotty didn't have a sidekick, but remember, this is the OS characters in an alternate timeline. So it's very likely (as Scotty says in the movie, he had a debate with a superior officer over transwarp beaming technology) that Keenser, the little alien guy, was maybe a partner in Scotty's projects before he was accidentally stranded on Delta Vega. Besides, I think Scotty's little buddy is awesome. :D

> Spock: You're Montgomery Scott. :D
>
> Scotty: Oh yeah, that's me. Well, unless there's another hard-working, equally-starved Starfleet officer around! :o
>
> Keenser: ME. -_-
>
> Scotty: KEENSER, SHUT UP! You could eat, like, a bean... and you're done. >.<

Comment: Scotty was not stranded on Delta Vega, he was assigned there for misplacing the Admiral's beagle.